# How can I tell rust two traits have the same type?

Tags: c++, algorithm, rust, iterator

I'm trying implement C++ [adjacent_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference) algo for rust iterator. `std::adjacent_different` by default uses the current value in a container subtracts its previous value, something like, if we have `[5, 7, 16]`, then after `adjacent_difference`, we get `[5, 7-5, 16-7]`

I try to do it in rust as an iterator extension, but found out that `Iterator::Item - Iterator::Item` is `std::ops::Sub::Output`, to make the `Iterator::next` return type happy, I have to do some weird things, like `Some(iter_item_value - <I as Iterator>::Item::default())` to get the correct type [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GKPcY78bK)

```rust
struct AdjacentDifference<I>
where I: Iterator
{
    prev: Option<I::Item>,
    it: I,
}

impl<I> Iterator for AdjacentDifference<I>
where I: Iterator, <I as Iterator>::Item: std::ops::Sub + Default + Copy,
{
    type Item = <<I as Iterator>::Item as std::ops::Sub>::Output;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match (self.it.next(), self.prev) {
            (None, _) => None,
            (Some(i), Some(p)) => {
                let r = i - p;
                self.prev = Some(i);
                Some(r)
            }
            (Some(i), None) => {
                self.prev = Some(i);
                Some(i - <I as Iterator>::Item::default()) // <<- really?
            }
        }
    }
}

trait AdjacentDifferenceExt: Iterator where Self: Sized,
{
    fn adjacent_difference(self) -> AdjacentDifference<Self>
    where <Self as Iterator>::Item: Copy,
    {
        AdjacentDifference {
            prev: None,
            it: self,
        }
    }
}

impl<I> AdjacentDifferenceExt for I where I: Iterator {}
```

It works, but I don't like this code very much, did I do this totally wrong? are there any better ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can tackle this.

For example, one option is just to specify the subtraction has the same type as the element itself:

```rust
impl<I> Iterator for AdjacentDifference<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: std::ops::Sub<Output = I::Item> + Copy,
{
    type Item = <<I as Iterator>::Item as std::ops::Sub>::Output;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match (self.it.next(), self.prev) {
            (None, _) => None,
            (Some(i), Some(p)) => {
                let r = i - p;
                self.prev = Some(i);
                Some(r)
            }
            (Some(i), None) => {
                self.prev = Some(i);
                Some(i)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This restricts the type you can use (for example, you won't be able to use [`Instant - Instant = Duration`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.64.0/src/std/time.rs.html#436-452)), but for most types this will be OK.

Another option is to specify that the iterator element type can be converted into the subtraction type via `From`:

```rust
impl<I> Iterator for AdjacentDifference<I>
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: std::ops::Sub + Copy,
    <I::Item as std::ops::Sub>::Output: From<I::Item>,
{
    type Item = <<I as Iterator>::Item as std::ops::Sub>::Output;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match (self.it.next(), self.prev) {
            (None, _) => None,
            (Some(i), Some(p)) => {
                let r = i - p;
                self.prev = Some(i);
                Some(r)
            }
            (Some(i), None) => {
                self.prev = Some(i);
                Some(i.into())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will implicitly work for the cases where the subtraction type is the element type thank to the blanket [`impl<T> From<T> for T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.64.0/src/core/convert/mod.rs.html#557-562).

Comment: Excellent! Your answer just opened many doors for me in rust world :)